# How to transfer lucene36 to lucene 40

Tags: java, lucene

Here is the code:

```
 public int docsContainTerm(Term tm) throws IOException {
  TermDocs termDocs = indexReader.termDocs(tm);
    //DocsEnum termDocs = indexReader.
    int count = 0;
    while (termDocs.next()) {
        if (indexReader.docFreq(tm) != 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

public int tf(Term tm, String docName) throws IOException {
    TermDocs termDocs = indexReader.termDocs(tm);
    while (termDocs.next()) {
        Document doc = indexReader.document(termDocs.doc());
        if (doc.get("filename").equals(docName)) {
            return termDocs.freq();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws CorruptIndexException, IOException {
    String indexDir = "indexDir";
    String docs = "docs";
    String query = "KENNEDY ADMINISTRATION PRESSURE ON NGO DINH DIEM TO STOP SUPPRESSING THE BUDDHISTS";
    Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File(indexDir));
    IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.open(dir);
    BM25 bm25 = new BM25(indexReader, docs);
    System.out.println(bm25.getContent("171"));
    System.out.println(bm25.htmlGetContent("171", query.toLowerCase()));
}
```

}

I have searched something about it, someone say i should change TermDocs to DocsEnum,but i don't know how to change.
Here is the error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

```
at BM25.main(BM25.java:269)
```

Comment: The third bullet down in the [Lucene 4.0 Migration Guide](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/MIGRATE.html) provides an example of using `DocsEnum` instead of `TermDocs`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Apache Lucene Migration Guide](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/MIGRATE.html),

1. Terms are now binary in nature (arbitrary byte[]), represented by the BytesRef class (which provides an offset + length "slice" into an existing byte[]).
2. Fields are separately enumerated (Fields.iterator()) from the terms within each field (TermEnum).
3. TermDocs is renamed to DocsEnum.
4. TermPositions is renamed to DocsAndPositionsEnum, and no longer extends the docs only enumerator (DocsEnum).
5. Deleted docs are no longer implicitly filtered from docs/positions enums. Instead, you pass a Bits skipDocs (set bits are skipped) when obtaining the enums. Also, you can now ask a reader for its deleted docs.
6. The docs/positions enums cannot seek to a term. Instead, TermsEnum is able to seek, and then you request the docs/positions enum from that TermsEnum.
7. TermsEnum's seek method returns more information.
8. TermsEnum has an ord() method, returning the long numeric ordinal (ie, first term is 0, next is 1, and so on) for the term it's not positioned to. There is also a corresponding seek(long ord) method. Note that these methods are optional; in particular the MultiFields TermsEnum does not implement them.
9. How you obtain the enums has changed. The primary entry point is the Fields class. Likewise for DocsAndPositionsEnum.